# How to use multiple where conditions in a laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I add two where conditions directly in a laravel blade?

```
({{ \App\Product::all()->where('category_id',$category->id  'user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count() }})
```

Comment: Please brief your problem with the code snippet. Use `code sample` from editor to format your code

Comment: ({{ \App\Product::where('category_id',$category->id)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count() }})

Comment: Does that even work? Won't `all()` fetch _ALL_ elements regardless of your `where` clauses? Also: [where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: And NO ONE to say that SQL just should NEVER  be used in Blade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use where condition in laravel blade as you can use them in your controller

```
({{ \App\Product::all()->where('category_id',$category->id)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count() }})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple where's after each other.

```
({{ \App\Product::where('category_id', $category->id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->count() }})
```

My suggestion is you read the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries) documentation, it explains everything you can do quite well.

---

I also noticed you started your query with a `all()` this will retrieve all rows from the database running those `where` conditions in your app. It's faster to run them on your database so by removing `all()` the query will be run with those `where` conditions as I think is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question I would like to point out 2 things

1) First do not use *\App\Product::all()* and then a where query. 
This way you are getting **all** the records from the DB as a collection and then the where operation is made on the collection, not in the DB. You do not want that, because if you have thousands or millions of records all of them would be returned.

2) It not a good practise to have queries inside your views. Simple get the result of the query somewhere inside your project and pass that value to the view through the Controller.

So for your query there are actually 2 ways to add multiple where clauses with laravel query builder

1) Using chained wheres:

```
({{ \App\Product::where('category_id',$category->id)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count() }})
```

2) Using an array inside the where:

```
({{ \App\Product::where(['category_id' => $category->id, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id])->count() }})
```